# java http Url connection for multiple post requests

Tags: java, post, httpurlconnection

I need help regarding the persistent httpurlconnection

my method header looks like

public boolean sendToAPI(ArrayList logs)
{

}

i need to be able to open the HttpUrlConnection and call multiple post request by iterating through the log list and then close the HttpurlConnection.

i always endup getting the below error:

Cannot write output after reading input.
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)

public void sendEvents(ArrayList logList, HttpURLConnection conn) throws IOException
    {

```
    DataOutputStream wr = null;


    try 
    {
         for(int i=0; i<logList.size(); i++)
         {
          conn.connect();   
             wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
             wr.writeBytes(logList.get(i));
             wr.flush();
             int nothing = conn.getResponseCode();
             String morenothing = conn.getResponseMessage();
             wr.close();
             conn.disconnect();
         }   
         if(wr != null) {
             wr.close();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
      if(conn != null) 
      {
        conn.disconnect(); 
      }
    }
```

Comment: You're probably not connecting correctly to the server. You need to post your code

Comment: updated the code please look in to that

Comment: Have a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051426/send-multiple-post-requests-through-a-dataoutputstream-in-java

Comment: Hey Max, I have seen that and implemented it to my project and had the same error.

Comment: Can you provide the full source (along with the details of the url connection) code so I can reproduce the issue locally?